# scraping data and writing to .csv file results with carriage returns inside each column

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

When scraping data with BS and writing to .csv file something is causing the data to add a carriage return before the text and after the text **within each cell** so effectively when you look at the cell, there is a blank row, then the data then another blank row, this causes excel to wrap the data.

Has anyone ever seen this occur? I know about writerow inserting a new row between each cell, but never seen it inside the cells themselves.

Crude example: star's indicate empty row within the cell

(*************************)

Data Written From BS

(*************************)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

quote_page = "http://www.starrpartners.com.au/selling?&agentOfficeID=0&officeID=0&alternateagentID=6435&agentID=6435&status=current&disposalMethod=sold&orderBy=sold&page=2"

page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
with open('index.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for band in soup.find_all('h5', attrs={'class': 'text-ltBlu'}):
        writer.writerow([band.text])
```

Side Note: The HTML within the page has an empty row before and after, would it be as simple as that? And if so, is there something i can do to ask BS to ignore empty rows?

```
<h5 class="text-ltBlu">

<b>North Parramatta</b><br>

<span class="text-dkBlu">1/13 Brickfield Street</span>

</h5>
```

Comment: See imgur link for further example http://imgur.com/a/cuYMb

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever looks this up and needs an answer:

The secret was in the writing method, I also needed to strip out any erroneous data.

Instead of:

```
writer.writerow([band.text])
```

We need to also add a strip command

```
writer.writerow([band.text.strip()])
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.